# How to fix bullet points in presentation?

Tags: beamer, positioning, notes, bullets

I try to write a proof by induction on multiple beamer slides, but I do not know how to stop the various notes from changing their position constantly (see images below). As far as I know I cannot use invisibility features since I am changing the text on the slides.
Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance

PS: The code looks like this so far

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Eine Beschränkung für automatische Monoide}
    \thref{Auto-Pump} auf Monoide 
    \begin{block}{}
        Sei $(M, \*)$ ein automatischer Monoid.\\
        Für jede $ s_1,...,s_m \in M$ gilt $ | \prod_{i=1}^m s_i|_L \leq max_{i \in \underline{m}} |s_i|_L + p_{\*} \lceil log (m) \rceil $.
    \end{block}
    Induktion über $ m \in \N $ \\
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 
        (IA):\\
        $ m = 1 $: $ |s_1|_L\leq |s_1|_L + 0 $
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Eine Beschränkung für automatische Monoide}
    \thref{Auto-Pump} auf Monoide
    \begin{block}{}
        Sei $(M, \*)$ ein automatischer Monoid.\\
        Für jede $ s_1,...,s_m \in M$ gilt $ | \prod_{i=1}^m s_i|_L \leq max_{i \in \underline{m}} |s_i|_L + p_{\*} \lceil log (m) \rceil $.
    \end{block}
    Induktion über $ m \in \N $ \\
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 
        (IA): $ \checkmark $
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Eine Beschränkung für automatische Monoide}
    \thref{Auto-Pump} auf Monoide
    \begin{block}{}
        Sei $(M, \*)$ ein automatischer Monoid.\\
        Für jede $ s_1,...,s_m \in M$ gilt $ | \prod_{i=1}^m s_i|_L \leq max_{i \in \underline{m}} |s_i|_L + p_{\*} \lceil log (m) \rceil $.
    \end{block}
    Induktion über $ m \in \N $ \\
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 
        (IA): $ \checkmark $
        \item
        (IS): $ m-1 \mapsto m $: $ m $ aufteilen nach $ u:= \lfloor m/2 \rfloor $\\
        $ x := \prod_{i=1}^{u}s_i $ und $ y := \prod_{i=u+1}^{m}s_i $, \\
        so folgt aus \thref{Auto-Pump} auf den (lokal finiten) Funktionsgraphen  von $ \* $ angewandt, dass $ | \prod_{i=1}^m s_i|_L \leq p_{\*} + max(|x|_L,|y|_L)$.\\
        Mit Induktionsvoraussetzung einsetzen: $ | \prod_{i=1}^m s_i|_L \leq p_{\*} + 
        max(
        max_{i \in \underline{u}} |s_i|_L+ p_{\*} \lceil log (u)\rceil ,
        max_{i \in \underline{m} \setminus \underline{u}} |s_i|_L + p_{\*} \lceil log (m-u)\rceil)
        \leq p_{\*} + max_{i \in \underline{m}} |s_i|_L + p_{\*} \* (\lceil log (u)\rceil + \lceil log (m - u)\rceil) $,\\ was nach Logarithmenrechnung $ \leq max_i |s_i|_L + p_{\*} \lceil log (m)\rceil$.
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Eine Beschränkung für automatische Monoide}
    \thref{Auto-Pump} auf Monoide
    \begin{block}{}
        Sei $(M, \*)$ ein automatischer Monoid.\\
        Für jede $ s_1,...,s_m \in M$ gilt $ | \prod_{i=1}^m s_i|_L \leq max_{i \in \underline{m}} |s_i|_L + p_{\*} \lceil log (m) \rceil $.
    \end{block}
    Induktion über $ m \in \N $ \\
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 
        (IA): $ \checkmark $
        \item
        (IS): $ \checkmark $
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please provide a minimal working example (MWE) of your current code.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. Does changing all instances of `\begin{frame}` to `\begin{frame}[t]`  address your issue?

Comment: How is `\*` defined? How or in which package is `\thref` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for multiple `frame` environments. You can do this with a single top aligned frame and some `\only` commands:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{theoremref}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools}

\newcommand*{\N}{\mathbb{N}}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
    \frametitle{Eine Beschränkung für automatische Monoide}
    \thref{Auto-Pump} auf Monoide 
    \begin{block}{}
        Sei $(M, \*)$ ein automatischer Monoid.\\
        Für jede $ s_1,...,s_m \in M$ gilt $ | \prod_{i=1}^m s_i|_L \leq max_{i \in \underline{m}} |s_i|_L + p_{\*} \lceil log (m) \rceil $.
    \end{block}
    Induktion über $ m \in \N $ \\
    \begin{itemize}
        \only<1>{\item 
        (IA):\\ $ m = 1 $: $ |s_1|_L\leq |s_1|_L + 0 $}
        \item<2-4> 
        (IA): $ \checkmark $
        \only<3>{\item
        (IS): $ m-1 \mapsto m $: $ m $ aufteilen nach $ u:= \lfloor m/2 \rfloor $\\
        $ x := \prod_{i=1}^{u}s_i $ und $ y := \prod_{i=u+1}^{m}s_i $, \\
        so folgt aus \thref{Auto-Pump} auf den (lokal finiten) Funktionsgraphen  von $ \* $ angewandt, dass $ | \prod_{i=1}^m s_i|_L \leq p_{\*} + max(|x|_L,|y|_L)$.\\
        Mit Induktionsvoraussetzung einsetzen: $ | \prod_{i=1}^m s_i|_L \leq p_{\*} + 
        max(
        max_{i \in \underline{u}} |s_i|_L+ p_{\*} \lceil log (u)\rceil ,
        max_{i \in \underline{m} \setminus \underline{u}} |s_i|_L + p_{\*} \lceil log (m-u)\rceil)
        \leq p_{\*} + max_{i \in \underline{m}} |s_i|_L + p_{\*} \* (\lceil log (u)\rceil + \lceil log (m - u)\rceil) $,\\ was nach Logarithmenrechnung $ \leq max_i |s_i|_L + p_{\*} \lceil log (m)\rceil$.}
        \item<4> 
        (IS): $ \checkmark $
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! That's exactly what I wanted! Thank you!